# How to make a private key and public key pair from a .cer file

Tags: openssl, public-key-encryption, private-key, public-key

I'm making a payment gateway integration, the API require a public key encryption and private key decryption for the data payload transfer. However, the payment gateway company only give me a .cer file. The file is a text content with 3 pairs of -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE-----.
The question is how can I make a private key and public key pair from this .cer file? I tried many different methods which got from google but still not able to make it work, could any expert help please!!

Comment: You can't _make_ a public or private key from a cer. I'd thing you need to present this certification for authentication purposes and can use pretty much any key, so just generate a fresh pair.

Comment: There's really only a few disconnected bits of information here, not enough to really know what's going on. You presumably followed some process to create a keypair (including the private key) and submit the public key to the payment gateway company. Please include all the details.

Comment: Refer to https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/visual-cobol/vc60/VS2017/BKCJCJCERTS001.html . Your client would have to provide you with one of these versions of the certificate to be able to get the public and private key from it. I would suggest having them provide the .pfx certificate file format. You can get everything from that and can convert it to other certificate versions.